# The Wolfram Kernel must be activated for WolframScript to use it

Tags: core-language, licensing

I'm using the [free Wolfram Engine for developers](https://blog.stephenwolfram.com/2019/05/launching-today-free-wolfram-engine-for-developers/), but somehow I cannot activate it.

```
> wolframscript
The Wolfram Engine requires one-time activation on this computer.

Visit https://wolfram.com/developer-license to get your free license.

Wolfram ID: someuser@somedomain.com
Password:
The Wolfram Kernel must be activated for WolframScript to use it.
```

I have claimed a developer license with my account.

[image]

What does "the Wolfram Kernel" mean, and how do I activate it?

Comment: The "Wolfram Kernel" is basically the core executable behind Mathematica. If it's failing to activate even with the correct password I'm not sure what we'll be able to do here. I'd try [Wolfram Support](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Registration).

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thanks, I have filed a ticket to them. In case someone encounters a similar problem, I'll update this post as soon as I figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Great! Also welcome to the Mathematica StackExchange. If you're new to Mathematica I'd let me recommend checking out [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) and maybe [this](https://mresources.github.io/tutorial/) (full disclosure I wrote the latter and it might be a bit disjoint). It's often a rough transition for programmers fluent in more standard languages like python, Java, and C (it was for me).

Comment: Did you get an e-mail from Wolfram with the subject "Welcome to the Wolfram Engine!"  If not, maybe it hasn't yet been processed for you.

Comment: @JimB Yes, actually I received that email 9 hours ago!

Comment: Hmmm.  Have you paid all of your traffic tickets?

Comment: @JimB Sorry but I didn't get you. What do you mean by "traffic tickets" and do I need to pay for a *free* developer license?

Comment: Sorry.  It was my poor attempt at localized humor.  (In the US one sometimes gets turned down for a loan, won't be hired for a job, can't get a driver's license renewed, etc. if one has outstanding tickets or warrants.  And as all-knowing as Wolfram-Alpha is, I don't think it has such information readily available.)

Comment: It might be a network connection issue with contacting the activation server, particularly if you are behind a firewall or a proxy.

Comment: @ilian Sorry for hijacking the thread, but I also have a similar issue with the activation on Linux (Fedora 29). The symptoms are: Free license acquired, e-mail received but `wolframscript` doesn't accept my credentials: `Incorrect username or password`. The credentials are, however, 100% correct. My uni MMA license is linked to that account and I can login at `user.wolfram.com` using that ID and  password. This is definitely not about proxy or firewall, tried to activate at the uni and at home and failed both times.  Should I contact the support or is this problem with Linux already known?

Comment: @vsht Does your password contain any special character? If YES, choose a new password that contains only letters and activate the license with the new password.

Comment: @bnuhero This was apparently the reason, with the new password it worked. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I find that the numpad don't work with wolframscript, therefore can be this the problem with the number in the password. Input number in the password with the principal keyboard.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue. Here is my solution with the [free Wolfram Engine for developers](https://www.wolfram.com/engine/) on Mac.

There are two relative apps in the launchpad after the engine was installed successfully. One is **Wolfram Engine**, the other is **WolframScript**.

[image: Wolfram Engine] [image: WolframScript]

Run the Wolfram Engine app instead of the WolframScript to activate your free license. This should fix the issue.

Note: Choose a password that doesn't contain any special character for your wolfram ID. Otherwise you always got the error message: 'Incorrect username or password' even if you provided the correct ID and password.

Comment: Can you expand your response? It is unclear what `Wolfram Engine` is and how you ran it.

Comment: Wolfram Engine is what reads your input and computes the outputs. The rest are interfaces

Comment: after your clarification I can confirm this solves the issue

Comment: Thanks, this post was very helpful! (The wolfram.com site does say -- at the time I write this -- to use wolframscript to register the license...)

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Comment: @AdrianKeister More details will be helpful.  How was your result? Have you got any error message? Which platform did you run the engine on?

Comment: This procedure (http://support.wolfram.com/kb/46070) failed. One important difference occurred between the screens on the website, and the screens I saw: because I have successfully installed the Wolfram Engine twice already, once on Windows 10 and once on Xubuntu Linux, Step 3 is different, and Steps 4-7 are not possible to execute. I can follow all the rest of the instructions to Step 20. When I try to execute that step, the window simply disappears after I enter the password. And yes, I still have a purely alphanumeric password with no special symbols.

Comment: If I try to run 'wolframscript' in a terminal, and enter the Wolfram ID and password that way, I get the text "The Wolfram Engine requires one-time activation on this computer." Then, when I enter my valid Wolfram ID and password, it doesn't work, and I get the text, "The Wolfram Kernel must be activated for WolframScript to use it."

Comment: @AdrianKeister I'm not sure. But you can try running `/Applications/Wolfram\ Engine.app/Contents/MacOS/Wolfram\ Engine` in a terminal to activate the license. Good luck.

Comment: In E-Mails with Wolfram, it came out that you can only activate twice per Wolfram ID, and I was trying to do my third.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Did they give any reason why only twice? Do they expect every potentially interested developer to communicate with them? Using a form ? ( https://www.wolfram.com/contact-us/ ) . Really?

Comment: @RolfMertig No, they didn't mention why. Presumably, this is part of their business model. I got around it simply by using more than one email address. I still have less than 5 installations.

Comment: Will the installation of Wolfram Engine interfere with existing installations of Mathematica?

Answer (score 10):

I am not sure whether they did this on purpose but to enable the walfram engine was quite implicit. (Yes WolframScript is different from Wolfram Kernel.)

Following method should work cross-platform.

**First Step**

Let's run `WolframScript` from the command line with argument `-v`, which is to ask WolframScript to output verbose log. Take Linux as an example,

```
$ wolframscript -v
```

Here we will be able to see an `url`:

`https://www.wolframcloud.com/users/user-current/activationkeys`

Quite self-explanatory this url gives us the `activation_key` that's associated with our machine/wolfram id. Let's copy paste it into an editor for now.

**Second Step**

we need to locate the actual `WolframKernel` in our installation folder. (the `.exe` for Windows.) Typically it should be under `/your_path_to_wolfram_installation/Executables/`. Bear in mind this is not the directory where you installed `wolframscript` (default would be `/usr/local/bin` in Linux).

In Linux run:

```
$ ./WolframKernel
```

It would then prompt you to enter `activation_key` here (the key we pasted into an text editor earlier on). Press enter to ignore it and then it'd go on to ask you for `activation_key` again (explicitly in format of `XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXX`) and an extra password. it also gave you your `machine id` and `math_id`. write down this `math_id`.

The password would be what we need to generate for ourselves. On the command line it'd give you an `url` again for generating this password:

`http://user.wolfram.com`

Leave the terminal window as is and move our focus to a browser.

Register our product using the `activation_key`. Once done, on the product page let's click on the product here:

[image]

In there we choose to manually activate:

[image]

Enter your `activation_key` and your `math_id` for this precious password. As usual, we write it down.

**Third Step**

Now go back to terminal window and enter the `activation_key` and `password`. This marks the completion of wolfram kernel activation.

**Fourth Step**

We can now just type `wolframscript` at command line and enter our usual `wolfram_id` details. i.e. registration email and password for wolfram online account.

Wolfram should be good to go now.

---

**Notes:**

1. I am not convinced this is how it's supposed to be activated; it just complicates matters and it has gone muted if this is actually part of official activation process for developer's version.
2. You should see that your activation key expires in 1 month time (this apparently goes against the announcement for a free developer version.)
3. Potentially you could also use your activation key to activate a `mathematica` copy; but that apparently is valid for a month, as explained in #1.
4. I'll try to get in touch with wolfram support for a clarification on this and update this answer accordingly.
5. Any command line application typically comes with `--help` argument as default and using this argument we'd normally find something constructive; among the small bits, `-v --verbose` is one that we'd notice very often as well.

Comment: Their customer service team is surpisingly unhelpful given wolfram/mathematica is probably one of the most advanced technical programming language in the world.

Comment: The activation key (that it gave me!) is invalid, for some reason.

Comment: I think that the correct URL to obtain the password for the activation key is this: https://user.wolfram.com/portal/ProductRegistration

Comment: You cannot run `wolframscript -v` without a vaild password.  This is an extremely confusing situation.

Comment: In my case, my actual WolframKernel was under /usr/local/Wolfram/.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem as described [here](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/195502) by someone else.

I install the **Wolfram Engine** on my Mac and succeed the activation according to the [support](https://support.wolfram.com/46070) on the Wolfram website. The **Wolfram Engine** is used [in Jupyter notebooks](https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter) with Visual Studio Code. Sometimes I encounter the problem that the **Wolfram Language kernel** is failed to load in Jupyter notebooks. At this point if I run the **WolframScript**, I get the following error message:

> The Wolfram Engine could not be activated using your Wolfram ID.
>
> This may have occurred because WolframScript has already activated a different
> installation of the Wolfram Engine using your account's limited
> free activation keys. Only two keys are generated
> when you create a free Wolfram Engine license using
> https://www.wolfram.com/engine/free-license/.
>
> For additional Wolfram Engine keys, contact Wolfram Research at
> https://www.wolfram.com/contact-us/.

I check the anwers on this page but none of the proposed methods works on my case (named *limited free activation keys* problem, a related but different problem). Such problem might be caused by the presence of multiple WolframKernel processes. The kernel cannot be initiated because there are already active kernel instances in the system's memory, especially [when the kernels are not properly closed using the Jupyter notebooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162707/how-to-close-ipython-notebook-properly).

My solution is as follows:

- Kill the process of **Wolfram Kernel**. This can be done by entering the `Exit[]` symbol in an open kernel session (e.g., WolframScript, Jupyter notebook), or using the Activity Monitor (Task Manager if you use Windows) to terminate the WolframKernel process.
- Kill other Wolfram related processes using the Activity Monitor.
- Restart the kernel (by running a WolframScript or a Jupyter notebook) and the problem is solved.