# Activation of Wolfram Engine asks for activation key instead of login

Tags: free-wolfram-engine

After downloading the wolfram engine 12.3 and running the command `wolframscript` in a terminal in windows it tells me:

```
Your Wolfram product is not activated or is experiencing a license-related problem.
Please activate the product at the following wolfram.exe location:
    /Wolfram Engine 12.3/wolfram.exe
```

Starting said file says:

```
Wolfram Language 12.3.1 Engine cannot find valid password.
For automatic Web Activation enter your activation key:
```

In all installation guides including the official one the user gets asked to sign in to their account for which I already have the engine activated. I however never got an activation-key and was also never during the installation process asked to sign in.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: How is the Wolfram Engine activated?
Launch WolframScript, located inside the installed product layout (see our support article). When it prompts, log in with the same account you provided during the download. This information is used to connect to the cloud and check for the two free keys associated with your account.
What should I do if WolframScript says my account has no valid keys?
Two keys are assigned to each account. If you have not logged in, you should do so to get the keys associated with your account. If both of the keys have already been used, you can contact us to reset them.

Comment: "When it prompts, log in" - as in the case of the asker, it does not prompt, it prints out the same message as in the question and exits.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem with Wolfram Engine 13.2.0 today. Inspired by [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/215202), I was able to solve the issue by the following steps:

1. In a web browser, login to your Wolfram account.
2. Visit https://www.wolframcloud.com/users/user-current/activationkeys. This is a JSON containing two activation keys for your account.
3. Run the program that asks for the activation key. Paste **one** of the two activation keys when it prompts `For automatic Web Activation enter your activation key`, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Wolfram Engine will be activated.

```
Automatic Web Activation received a password.

Creating password file entry in:
/xxx/.WolframEngine/Licensing/mathpass
```

This works on my Ubuntu, but I suppose the solution will also work on other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, calling from the command line:

```
wolframscript -username [your_username]
```

where `[your_username]` should be your WolframID, that is the same as your Wolfram User Portal login name (I assume).

Then hit enter and type your password when prompted. Result:

```
Success. Saving connection data.
```

Also, you may have to manually activate, using your activation key, as:

```
wolframscript -activate [your_activationkey]
```

It worked for me for Wolfram Engine 13.2.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the exact same error message when executing WolframKernel:

```
$ WolframKernel
Wolfram Language 13.3.0 Engine for Linux x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2023 Wolfram Research, Inc.

Wolfram Language 13.3.0 Engine cannot find a valid password.

For automatic Web Activation enter your activation key
(enter return to skip Web Activation):
```

In my case the problem was that another instance of WolframKernel was already running. After identifying the processes with (for non-Linux systems see https://support.wolfram.com/36360?src=mathematica)

```
$ ps -ef | grep Wolfram
```

and terminating them both WolframKernel and wolframscript worked as expected again.